# How to make new tab open a blank page in firefox?

Tags: 12.04, firefox

Today ubuntu software center asked me to update things as usual, and I accepted.

But now when I open a new tab in firefox, it shows 9 'mini pages' taken from the history of visited pages.

How can I remove that? Does it have something to do with the 'ubuntu firefox modifications' addon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another way if you want to get rid of it permanently. If you are happy with Matt2's solution there is no need to do so. I wanted remove it totally, because the mouse gestures provide by the extension [All-in-one Gestures](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/all-in-one-gestures/) don't work on new tabs with the new startpage (by the way, I think its official name is *new tab page*).

### Step 1

Enter this address to the location bar and confirm that you will be careful:

```
about:config
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

### Step 2

Search for the preference with name:

```
browser.newtab.url
```

**Update:** you can set browser.newtabpage.enabled (Step 2) to False (Step 3) instead of changing browser.newtab.url.

[image: Screenshot 2]

### Step 3

Double click to modify and set the value to

```
about:blank
```

or

```
about:startpage
```

if you prefer to see your own startpage (set its url in the standard preferences dialog).

Close the window, you're done!

Answer (score 6):

On your new tab in Firefox, you see that button in the top right corner?  Looks like a grid?  Click it.

This is a new feature in Firefox and has nothing to do with any Ubuntu addons.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit → Preferences → General → Start Page and set it to:

```
about:blank
```

Comment: This won't work in Firefox 13. This sets the startpage, but firefox loads the page `about:newtab`.

Comment: You are right, sorry.. it works only in new window but not on Ctrl-T..